# Strange QuickLook Error

Tags: macos, memory, error, console

I recently installed an SSD (m4 crucial latest firmware) with TRIM enabled on my late 2011 MBP 13". I did a clean install of Mountain Lion 10.8.1, enabled FileVault 2 and everything was working fine for about 2 weeks until Finder just started randomly killing itself every time I mounted a DMG or just launched some random app.

At the time I was getting this error:

```
com.apple.quicklook.satellite[205]: [QL] Using too much memory (308 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.
```

Backed up all my files manually and did another clean install. Installed a few applications, re-enabled FileVault, waited 2 days, everything was running fine. Decided it was time to copy my files back over.

Whilst copying over Ethernet with Wifi enabled, I disabled the wifi, Finder hangs had to hard reset. On reboot the error was back:

```
12/09/2012 23:24:27.883 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[172]: [QL] Using too much memory (300 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.
12/09/2012 23:24:29.883 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[172]: [QL] Using too much memory (616 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.
12/09/2012 23:24:29.943 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D[172]) Exited: Killed: 9
12/09/2012 23:24:29.943 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2 seconds
12/09/2012 23:24:33.509 awacsd[69]: Exiting
12/09/2012 23:24:35.559 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100002 created
12/09/2012 23:24:36.108 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[205]: [QL] Using too much memory (308 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.
12/09/2012 23:24:36.129 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D[205]) Exited: Killed: 9
12/09/2012 23:24:39.824 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication[108]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing<br>
```

I cannot find anything similar on Google and for the life of me cannot figure out what is wrong.

It's giving me the same error on every reboot and every 3-7 minutes. It's only matter of time I suspect before Finder starts going nuts. It's also worth mentioning that very few applications are installed at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the copy source look like? Lots of files, NAS or what?

Comment: 25Gb worth off of a NAS drive

Comment: I did find this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2315503?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, it turned out to be a 4.3mb CSV file on my desktop that quicklook had issue with. Deleted it and everything went back to normal... Strange.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How did you figure out it was this document? It may help others looking to resolve similar problems in the future.

Comment: Having done numerous clean installs, I finally realised it only ever happened when I started copying my data from my NAS back onto my mac - 300GB worth. In order to find the culprit I thought I would **only** copy a folder I really needed which were a few documents I had, about 100mb worth. Its when I copied that folder I realised that my system was misbehaving and started copying each and every file one by one until I came across that particular CSV file. I have other CSV files but that specific one for some reason just didn't agree with my system.